# Is there a unified source code documentation generator?

Tags: documentation, source-code, documentation-generation

I'm currently working on a client's project that involves programming in multiple languages. It has gotten to the point where the amount of source code for each language has grown to such a large volume that it's difficult to navigate. Especially when returning to that code base after an extensive break working on other issues.

Currently, we have repositories in `C#`, `Java`, `PHP` and `Javascript`. All this source code follows proper code documentation annotations, but those code docs are relative to the language. `PHP` and `Java` for example have very different comment documenting methods.

When we generate `HTML` from the source code to review the documentation. It's all different for each language.

Is there a doc generator that works for all those languages that creates consistent `HTML` for all our projects?

Comment: [Doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/) claims to support C#, Java and PHP. Maybe it can also work with Javascript.